# How to find an overloaded method in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, overloading

When writing something like

```
doit(43, 44, "hello");
```

the compiler knows which overloaded method is to be called. When I want to do the same via reflection, I need to find out myself, that the method is

```
doit(Integer, double, CharSequence...);
```

and obtain it via something like

```
Class[] types = {Integer.class, double.class, CharSequence[].class};
declaringClass.getDeclaredMethod("doit", types);
```

I wonder if there's already something allowing me to write just

```
Method m = getMethod(declaringClass, "doit", 43, 44, "hello");
```

I wonder if somebody did this already, as the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) is a bit complicated in this respect.

---

Actually, behaving *exactly* like the compiler is impossible as in [Phase 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2) the compiler accepts only methods matching without boxing and unboxing. When calling my hypothetical `getMethod` from above, the distinction between primitives and their wrappers is already lost (because of autoboxing when passing arguments via varargs). This problem seems to have no solution, so let's ignore it.

As suggested in an answer, `BeanUtils.invokeMethod` comes close. It's supposed to find the best match, whatever it means. Looking at [MethodUtils](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/beanutils/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.java?view=markup)`.getMatchingAccessibleMethod` shows that

- it knows nothing about varargs
- it's non-deterministic

so I'm looking for something better.

Comment: Out of curiosity, for what reason do you want this? Is there a use case that applies?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Not really. Once I needed a simple way for calling private methods (I didn't like to make them `@VisibleForTesting`), so I wrote a tiny utility class and found out it's far from perfect. It's good enough for what I need it for, but I became curious if it's possible to do it "right".

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use [Bean Utils from Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils):

```
public static Method getAccessibleMethod(
        Class clazz,
        String methodName,
        Class[] parameterTypes)
```

According [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#getAccessibleMethod%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%5b%5d%29):

> Return an accessible method (that is, one that can be invoked via
>   reflection) with given name and parameters. If no such method can be
>   found, return null. This is just a convenient wrapper for
>   getAccessibleMethod(Method method).
>
> Parameters:
>   **clazz** - get method from this class
>   **methodName** - get method with this name
>   **parameterTypes** - with these parameters types

The implementation get the accessible method and goes up in the hierarchy until it founds a match to it.

### Direct to the Invocation

In order to perform invocation directly as you asked, you could use this method from the same API:

```
public static Object invokeExactMethod(
        Object object,
        String methodName,
        Object[] args,
        Class[] parameterTypes)
        throws
        NoSuchMethodException,
        IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException
```

or even

```
public static Object invokeExactMethod(
        Object object,
        String methodName,
        Object[] args)
        throws
        NoSuchMethodException,
        IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException
```

that first locates the method using `getAccessibleMethod` and later on invokes it.

Comment: This doesn't work: `getAccessibleMethod` requires parameter types, and finds nothing when given the real types of arguments. `invokeExactMethod` only uses `getAccessibleMethod`. I've found `invokeMethod`, which really tries to find the matching method, but it doesn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

The [`MethodHandle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) is a new way to get a overloaded method using a signature (java 7):

Example:

```
static class A {
    public String get() {
        return "A";
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    public String get() {
        return "B";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(String.class);
    MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(A.class, "get", mt);;

    System.out.println(mh.invoke(new B()));
}
```

Outputs:

```
B
```

Comment: You've answered a different question, namely "How to invoke an overridden method?", while I was asking "How to invoke the method *the compiler would choose* for my arguments?". Nonetheless, +1 as I learned something new and interesting.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the whole question.. I also just learned about the new `java.lang.invoke` package,but your in luck, I [answered just such a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188919/how-to-search-for-java-api-methods-by-type-signature) a long time ago (you need to add the variable argument thing, and remove the "all permutations of arguments" but that seems like a simple thing to do! :))

Comment: The linked answer may find *all* possibly applicable methods, but I want the one the *compiler chooses to invoke*.

Comment: the question is about overloaded methods not overriding.