# Find if method is overloaded using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, overloading

There is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765627/how-to-find-an-overloaded-method-in-java) regarding this but in the answers the parameter types are used.

My question is that having a class what should be done to find out whether the method returned using reflection is overloaded or not?

Possible ways can be:
1) Looping to find the same method again

```
    List<Method> overloaded = new ArrayList<Method>();
    Method[] declaredMethods = A.class.getDeclaredMethods();

    for(int i = 0; i < declaredMethods.length; i++){
        for(int j = (i + 1); j < declaredMethods.length; j++){
            if(declaredMethods[j].getName().equals(declaredMethods[i].getName())){
                overloaded.add(declaredMethods[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(overloaded);
```

Is there some way to find out overloaded methods which has a better algorithmic complexity than this?
Does some library provide the same functionality?

Comment: for better complexity, you could use a `Map<String, List<Method>>` where the keys are the names.

Comment: why do you want to optimize it? i doubt that there is any need for further inprovement. leave it as it is.

Comment: @AlexWien I did not necessarily wanted to optimize it but was just curious whether java or some other library can provide the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Set`. if the `add()` operation returns `false` the method name is already in the set.
Java Reflection has no method to determine whether a method is overloaded.