# Access overloaded method via Reflection Api

Tags: java, reflection

How to distinguish a class overloaded method using Reflection e.g. :

`method()` and `method(int arg)`

```
void invoke(Object object, String methodName, int id) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName).invoke(object, int.class);
}
```

And call to this function :

```
getV(new Object(), "method", 33);
```

And it returns error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`, That mean the method with no arguments is choosed by default. If i invoke the method without the int parameter it will work. I ask how to distinguish the overloaded method's ? I have read the docs for `Class.getDeclaredMethod` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html Also there is an old post on SO but both sources aren't answering the same question 
[How to find an overloaded method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765627/how-to-find-an-overloaded-method-in-java). Ofcourse Class.Object dosen't have method with name method i just used it for the example.

Comment: @Holger Didn't you see int.class there ? I choose the method with 1 parameter.

Comment: @Holger I got it : ) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the parameter types to the lookup method, not the invoke method:

```
void invoke(Object object, String methodName, int id) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, int.class).invoke(object, id);
}
```

But keep in mind that `getClass()` returns the actual class, which could be a subclass of the intended class, whereas `getDeclaredMethod` does not seach superclasses. `getMethod` does search superclasses, but only considers `public` methods.

To consider non-public methods within the type hierarchy, you would have to loop through the superclasses yourself when the method has not been found.