# Signature based search for C++

Tags: c++, search, reference, static-analysis

Is there a tool that would allow searching a C++ code base on type signature? Someone recently pointed me to the powerful Haskell tool [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[b]) and I'd love to have something similar for our codebase.

To expand, I'm interested in doing queries of the following type:

I have a class `Foo`, and I know there exists a function that maps it to an associated `Bar`, but I can't recall the name of the function. I'd like to be able to ask something: "Give me all the functions that take a `Foo`, and provide a `Bar`.

A couple of notes:

- [This is pretty much exactly my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188919/how-to-search-for-java-api-methods-by-type-signature), but for Java. Unfortunately, the solution presented there requires reflection.
- It seems like Doxygen has the information to do something like this, however, I'm not sure how one would configure it to provide this. Is there a tool that consumes Doxygen XML to provide this kind of functionality?
- Fuzzy answers are acceptable! C++ has a complex enough feature set that the tool may not be 100% accurate -- but it may still be better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can test [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com), it has a powerful code query language([CQLinq](http://www.cppdepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Features.aspx)) to query as you want your code, for example in your case you can execute query like this one:

```
from m in Methods where m.Params.Where(p=>p.ParamType=="Foo").Count()>0
&& m.ReturnType.Name=="Bar"
select m
```